# Aptana 3.1.1 - Character encoding

Tags: encoding, character, aptana

I have updated to Aptana 3.1.1 and now my projects writen in ISO-8859-1 show some characters very wrong. There's a workaround, but then my UTF-8 projects gets wrong characters.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's this bug here: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-4656. Basically there is now a default encoding type being set.

The change is being reverted as it appears to cause more annoyance than help, but in the meantime, you can either do:

1. General > Content Types > File Type > Default encoding and set it to whatever you wish.
2. There will be updates to the RC and beta streams tonight with a revert of that change.

Comment: This changes encoding for all files. What if I have project in windows 1251 along with project in utf-8?